# Error Running Local Test on Real Device using Xamarin UITest and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, uitest

I have a test fixture that contains several tests. When I run this test fixture in Test Cloud it works fine, but when I run locally the first test succeeds, but all subsequent tests fail with this message:

> "SetUp : System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : An error occurred while sending the request.
>
> System.Net.WebException : The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."

I included the stack trace below. It's like it can't launch the app for the other tests. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and running the test using Test Explorer.

Result StackTrace:

> at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient.SendData(String endpoint, String method, HttpContent content, ExceptionPolicy exceptionPolicy, Nullable`1 timeOut)
>   at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient.PostUntilExpectedResultReceived(String endpoint, String arguments, String expectedContent, Int32 retries)
>
> at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.HttpApplicationStarter.Execute(String intentJson)
>   at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.LocalAndroidAppLifeCycle.LaunchApp(String appPackageName, ApkFile testServerApkFile, Int32 testServerPort)
>
> at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.LocalAndroidAppLifeCycle.LaunchApp(ApkFile appApkFile, ApkFile testServerApkFile, Int32 testServerPort)
>   at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp..ctor(IAndroidAppConfiguration appConfiguration, IExecutor executor)
>   at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AndroidAppConfigurator.StartApp(AppDataMode appDataMode)
>
> at PerfectRoomTest.AppInitializer.StartApp(Platform platform) in C:\Projects\PerfectRoomXamarin\PerfectRoom-Branch\PerfectRoomTest\AppInitializer.cs:line 15
>
> at PerfectRoomTest.Tests.BeforeEachTest() in C:\Projects\PerfectRoomXamarin\PerfectRoom-Branch\PerfectRoomTest\Tests.cs:line 43
>   --WebException
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>   Result Message:
>
> SetUp: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
>
> System.Net.WebException : The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

Comment: I too am experiencing this issue.  What version of Xamarin.UITest are you using?

Comment: I tried the same tests in Xamarian Studio on Mac and they worked fine for Android (got errors about not being able to contact Calabash for the iOS tests but that's my fault).

Comment: I now have all the tests passing on Xamarin Studio on Mac for both Android and iOS.  But Visual Studio still fails after 1st test.

Comment: My Xamarin.UITest version is 2.0.7.

Comment: I have opened an issue with Xamarin.  I will let you know what i find out.

Comment: Have you heard anything from Xamarin. I have an open issue with them also, but haven't heard anything from them.

Comment: No, no word yet.  I even have a success engineer assigned to it, but they haven't reached out to me yet as they give priority to premium partners first (I work for a Xamarin registered partner, just not premium).

Answer (score 0):

Added this in case someone still running into this problem. I believe that it is common if you are Unit Testing in UnitTest, NUnit, XUnit (it doesn't matter), I'm on VS 2022.  I recently had this problem and it caused me days to resolve when I ran into this post. Basically, the Android emulators in Visual Studio are very meticulous when it comes to apps doing too much when initializing the app and it disconnects if it senses is going for too long. There is nothing I found to force the emulator to complete rendering or extend it. The way I solved it is by unloading some of the stuff from the initializing construct. Just add basic stuff to help render the app and do not add any extended methods (async or sync, it doesn't matter).  I was seeding a folder structure during initialization and that was apparently causing a heartburn. Note that the app was installing and running fine everywhere except launching from a Xamarin Test framework.  The only use I see in Xamarin logs for the http request is that it seems to ping the emulator. Pay particular attention to methods that are async or use async along the way. I had to simplify one of those to make it work within UnitTest framework..